# Python - Create many dummy variables from one text variable?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-cleaning, preprocessing

I'm trying to create dummy variables for a variable that has text data in rows.

Data in 1st row is:
`{"Wireless Internet","Air conditioning",Kitchen,Heating,"Family/kid friendly",Essentials,"Hair dryer",Iron,"translation missing: en.hosting_amenity_50"}`

and Data in 2nd row is:
`{TV,"Cable TV",Internet,"Wireless Internet",Kitchen,"Indoor fireplace","Buzzer/wireless intercom",Heating,Washer,Dryer,"Smoke detector","Carbon monoxide detector","First aid kit","Fire extinguisher",Essentials}` and many more.

What I now want to do is, to create dummy variables out of that variable. For example from the above data:
one variable named `Wireless Internet` with `0` ans `1` in rows &
another variable named `Cable TV` with `0` and `1` in rows &
another variable named `Kitchen` with `0` and `1` in rows and so on.

`sklearn` for python has `OneHotEncoder` class which creates dummy variable named everything in a row considering all rows with unique values. That is not what I want to do here. I first have to split text in all rows and create dummy variables for them. How do I do that?

Expected results are, multiple columns like
`Wireless Internet    Cable TV      Kitchen`
`1                     0             1`
`0                     1             1`
`1                     0             1`

[image: example of transformation]
link to data(column named `amenities`) - https://www.kaggle.com/stevezhenghp/airbnb-price-prediction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the kaggle page, there is a [kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/jaggu22/one-hot-encoding-for-variables-with-multi-text) available which focuses on exactly your problem. This is the code from user *JAGADEESHWARA VARA PRASAD*:

```py
# load your dataset into df
df = pd.read_csv("../input/train.csv")

# trimm { } symbols and split at ',' and trimm " from each word
l = [[word.strip('[" ]') for word in row[1:-1].split(',')]
     for row in list(df['amenities'])]

# form a set of distinct text
cols = set(word for row in l for word in row)
cols.remove('')

# create and fill new data frame
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
for row_idx in range(len(l)):
    for col in cols:
        new_df.loc[row_idx,col]=int(col in l[row_idx])

print(new_df)
```